# how i show a dWord value in Messagebox api function

Tags: c++, messagebox, dword

i want show a message dialog with a dword value like this

MessageBox(0, (LPCWSTR) hProcess  ,TEXT("My MessageBox Info"),MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

hProcess  is a DWORD value but it when messagebox appear , body part of message that should show dowrd value is empty.

Answer (score 7):

```
TCHAR msg[100];

StringCbPrintf(msg, 100, TEXT("%d"), hProcess);

MessageBox(NULL, msg, TEXT("My MessageBox Info"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
```

Comment: A `DWORD` is an unsigned type, so you should use `%u` instead of `%d`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *s = (char*)malloc(10);
sprintf(s, "%d", hProcess);
MessageBox(NULL, s, ...);
free(s);
```

Comment: it raise below error.
error C2664: 'MessageBoxW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char *' to 'LPCWSTR'

Comment: You can just cast it, sorry.
MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)s, ...);

Comment: No, you cannot type-cast a `char*` to a `wchar_t*` (which is what `LPCWSTR` is).  You need to either 1) use `TCHAR` instead of `char` and `_stprintf()` instead of `sprintf()`, or 2) use `MessageBoxA()` instead of `MessageBox()`.

Answer (score 1):

First convert the value to a string, then display it in message box.

Take a look at this: [ultoa](http://www.juanfc.lcc.uma.es/EDU/LibrosEnRed/sobreC++/c++reference/ultoa.html)